# Can I make a network for devices to connect to my computer (to use it as a proxy)?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, proxy, tor

I would like to use my Windows 7 laptop to host a network that I can connect other devices to, and use the laptop (and Tor, if need be) as a proxy, to make devices I connect with will be anonymously connected. How would I do this?

I am moderately skilled with network configuration on my laptop, and would like to be able to connect devices to my computer without having to use the internet router to port the connection over to my laptop.

The ideal situation would be to connect a device *directly* to my laptop, which then connects to the router and by extension the internet. If possible, I would like to route the connection through Tor.

(If this is not the correct website to post this on, please direct me to the correct one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Wi-Fi hotspot with two commands (in `cmd`):

1. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=YOURDESIREDNAME pass=YOURDESIREDPASS`
2. `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

To stop the hostednetwork, type: `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork`

Comment: I got it up and working but I have two questions- 1) How do I shut it down when I'm done with it? 2) Is there a way to route the traffic through a SOCKS4 proxy? If so, how would I do this?